# API request open method not a function error in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, api

[My weather app on Code Pen](https://codepen.io/Hello911/pen/WEbyva?editors=0010)

Code(Sorry if it's too much):

```js
var button=document.getElementById('submit');
var zipcode;
var lat;
var lng;
var weather;
var iconId;
var temp;

/*takes what the user enters*/
button.addEventListener('click',getValue);
function getValue(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  zipcode=document.getElementById('zipcode').value;
  getCity();
}
//API request to Google Geocode 
function getCity(){
  var req=new XMLHttpRequest;
  req.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200){
      var myData=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      var myCity=myData.results[0].address_components[1].short_name;
      lat=myData.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
      lng=myData.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
      document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML=lat;
      document.getElementById('lng').innerHTML=lng;
      document.getElementById('city').innerHTML=myCity;
    }//if function end
  }//onreadystate function end
  req.open('GET','https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+zipcode, true);
  req.send();
  getWeather();
}
//API request Dark Sky Weather
function getWeather(){
  var request=XMLHttpRequest;
  request.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200){
      var myWeather=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      weather=myWeather.currently.summary;
      document.getElementById('weather').innerHTML=weather;
      console.log(myWeather);
    }//if ends
  }//onready end
  request.open('GET','https://api.darksky.net/forecast/6231bad7d2bf09aa53301a4227b7c1af/'+lat+','+lng, true);
  request.send();
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type=text placeholder='zipcode' id='zipcode'></input>
  <input type='submit' id='submit'></input>
</form>

<ol>
  <li>City Name: <span id='city'></span></li>
  <li>Latitude: <span id='lat'></span></li>
  <li>Longitude: <span id='lng'></span></li><br>
  
  <li>Temperature(F): <span id='temp'></span></li>
  <li>Icon: <span id='icon'></span></li>
  <li>Weather: <span id='weather'></span></li><br>
  <li>Wind(mph): <span id='wind'></span></li>
  <li>Sunrise: <span id='sunrise'></span></li> 
  <li>Sunset: <span id='sunset'></span></li>
</ol>
```

Ok here is the logic of my code. You enter zipcode and press 'submit', and triggers Event Listener that has a callback function 'getValue', which stores the zipcode in a variable and execute getCity() function, which turns the zipcode into City Name and Lat and Lng.

I am not sure where to put the execution of my getWeather() function that uses the Lat and Lng to get weather conditions. I initially put it right after getCity() in the getValue() function definition, but **I thought that would leaves no time for the Lat and Lng value to be obtained from the first API.** So I put in the getCity() function definition.

The getCity() function works good and turns the zipcode into City Name and Lat Lng. But the problem is the getWeather() function that should return a description like 'Rainy'.

Error in Chrome Console:
[image]

**EDIT**: I add 'new' keyword.  var request= new XMLHttpRequest; That is a silly typo. Here is the new error:

[image]

**!!EDIT 2: HUGE DISCOVERY:** I think I know why. But I don't know how to fix it. It is SCOPE! I try **console.log(lat+' and '+lng);** in the definition of getWeather() function, the console says 'undefinedandundefined'. The only place where I can get the longitude and latitude is if I place the console.log inside the definition of getCity() function, where the 1st API converts the zipcode entered to lat and lng.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request object needs to be instantiated. Try doing this: `var request = new XMLHttpRequest();`.

Edit: You need to explicitly label the request header. `request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`

Comment: I corrected that typo. I updated the question with a image of the new error in console.

Comment: Please make sure you include the parentheses after XMLHttpRequest as well.

Comment: @user132522 I have also updated my response with the change.

Comment: Why is that needed? It never happened with the first API.

Comment: Not too sure - could be how the server is configured (although it is returning a 400 error). I would double check that the API url is correct, if setting the header did not work.

Comment: I know why now. The Dark Sky ban people from directly using their free API from Code Pen. It is a cross origin issue